# Can Iterable.filter() skip processing with "constant" (including short circuited) Predicates?

Tags: java, guava

I just looked at the AndPredicate and the ALWAYS_FALSE predicates and didn't find any indication that an AndPredicate noticed an ALWAYS_FALSE component to short circuit itself.

It seems like there may be a number of optimization opportunities if a Predicate is known to be ALWAYS_TRUE or ALWAYS_FALSE. For example, could Iterables.filter(Iterable,Predicate) just return the input Iterable(perhaps an unmodifiable view of it) with an ALWAYS_TRUE Predicate, and an empty Iterable with an ALWAYS_FALSE Predicate?

Similarly an AndPredicate which contains an ALWAYS_FALSE could be considered an ALWAYS_FALSE for this type of optimization (and OrPredicate with an ALWAYS_TRUE, etc.)

Is this optimization already in place, and I missed it in my casual search, or are there reasons (side effect behavior changed?) why this would not be a good idea?

Comment: This is not a question about how to program with the Guava library, but rather a suggestion for the Guava developers that should have been posted on a Guava mailing list


Answer (score 3):

There are reasons why this would not be a good idea: it wouldn't end up being an "optimization."

Specifically, the users who'd be affected by this optimization are a very small fraction of the users of `Predicates.and` and `Predicates.or`.  Let's say for the purposes of argument that this is 1%, though honestly I think that's probably generous.  Not many users are knowingly passing `ALWAYS_TRUE` to `Predicates.or`.

Now, is the win for the 1% worth the cost of *the check to see if the optimization is possible* to the 99%?  To speed up that 1%, you've slowed down everyone else -- and everyone else massively outnumbers the users getting sped up.

It's possible that the JIT might do enough inlining to figure out that it can do an equivalent optimization -- i.e. working out that the `if` condition is always `true`, and skipping the if statement.  But the JIT is heavily optimized to only do optimizations that, on average, are worth the time invested in checking whether the optimization is applicable.

Comment: Hi Louis, thanks for your response. Agree the likelihood of users explicitly using Predicates.alwaysXX() is low. My specific case was a Predicates.in(Collection) where the collection was the result of a few Set intersections. Realizing that the final Set could be empty got me thinking along this line - Predicates.in() could return ALWAYS_FALSE for empty collections. The overhead of checking for ALWAYS_FALSE/TRUE where needed feels very small, comparable to the (nearly) obsessive null checking existant now throughout guava, relative to a potentially very heavyweight iteration.

Comment: The null checks are, generally speaking, _validity_ checks, as opposed to optimization checks.  (In addition, your specific case would require even more weird edge-casing: `Predicates.in(Collection)` would have to check if the collection is mutable, since even a currently empty collection could expand later...)

Comment: Agree that validity and optimization are different kinds of checks, but I still wonder how negatively it would impact the 99(.999)% case. I hadn't considered the initially empty Collection passed to the in() mutating during the filter(). It seems like having a side effect like that might be error-prone/confusing, but if that's the contract of Predicate.in() then this optimization could break things.. too bad. Thanks for the responses.